# How to move Ubuntu installation to new drive

Tags: hard-drive

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on a 250 GB hdd. This HDD has developed bad sector and I received replaced drive from Manufacturer. I am also running a RAID1 using mdm.

I want to move the existing setup to new hard drive.

Can someone please give suggestions.

Thanks for your answers.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a RAID and your previous drive had problems, the best solution is installing from 0, since `dd` don't understand damaged sectors, and could migrate them (with damaged data) to your new drive and cause problems thereafter.

Do a backup of your `/home` directory, and restore all your data in the new drive. For having a list of all software/packages installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections > package_list
```

Then on your new system run:

```
sudo apt-get update && cat package_list | sudo dpkg --set-selections && sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

With that, you will have a fresh copy of your system without possible problems that could cause the old one.

Answer (score 0):

*dd* is your friend :)

This command can be used to clone one drive into another.

Read more here: https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning

Copy of answer for convenience:

> dd is most certainly the best cloning tool, it will create a 100%
>   replica simply by using the following command. I've never once had any
>   problems with it.
>
> dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=32M Be aware that while cloning every
>   byte, you should not use this on a drive or partition that is being
>   used. Especially applications like databases can't cope with this very
>   well and you might end up with corrupted data.